# YII2 get table rows where id is not equal to array elements

Tags: arrays, yii2, notin

I have an array of elements in the form of:

```
Array ( [0] => 16 [1] => 14 [2] => 1 [3] => 13 )
```

Now I need to extract only rows which ID is not one of the values in the array. Right now I'm using the following code:

```
$items = ArrayHelper::map(User::find()->where(['<>', 'id', $array])->all(), 'id', 'name');
```

Unfortunately this compares the ids in the database with just the first element of an array.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `not in` instead of `<>`

Comment: Yeah, thank you! Tried that earlier also, but somehow it denied to work.

Answer (score -1):

You can try following code example,

```
$arr = [16,14,1,13];
$items = ArrayHelper::map(User::find()->where(['id'=>$arr])->all(), 'id', 'name');
```

It works for me.